# PHP Include to use a relative path

Tags: php, configuration

This is a *BAD* idea, and I'm only asking this because I'm trying to reproduce a *PRODUCTION* system, in which I currently have limited control.

I need to enable relative paths within php includes. For example: include('../../session.php');

I understand that this is a bad idea, I know the consequences and how to properly configure with the use of `__DIR__`. I am planning work items which will solve this issue, but in the meantime, I need to sort another dependency issue.

How can I temporarily enable this to replicate the current *Production* system? I can't find anything useful in php.ini

Comment: uh..you should be allowed to include using a relative path already.  are you getting an error?  including happens based of the current working directory which you can find out by calling `getcwd()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to enable relative paths for `include()` and `require()`, they work by default.

I even don't know any setting which would prevent the usage of relative paths.

Be aware that paths are always relative to the current working directory (cwd) of your script. Use `echo getcwd()` to print the cwd.